# find average of calculated field in cognos 10.1

Tags: cognos

I have a calculated field `a/b` which makes sense at week level, where `a` is last of period metric and `b` is sum of the period metric. I need to find `avg(a/b)` for the weeks that fall under a month and not `end_of_month(a)/sum(b) for the month`. I made my `a/b` metric with regular aggregate as calculated and then monthly average metric with regular aggregate as average, but it doesn't work. The report is a crosstab report. How can I solve this?

Edit: `a` is end on hand inventory, `b` is sales, `a/b` is weeks of supply. Both `a` and `b` spread along product/location/time dimensions. For `a`, I've set its regular aggregate for time as last.

Your form of expression gives me error, so, I tried `average((total([a] for [week]))/(total([b] for [week])))` which is error-free but doesn't give correct result. I used total[a] because it still has to sum along other dimensions except time. Any ideas?

I was also trying an alternative way- get the individual weeks of supply and then derive a new metric as (first week wos + ...+fifth week wos)/5. But I get a warning when I try to put a case statement as "Relational query objects are being used in conjunction with Dimensionally-modeled relational objects", and the metric give garbage value. How can I apply case involving relational item in query items of measure dimension?

Comment: I read your question two more times and I did not fully understand what do request. If you have additional fields you would like to sum you need to add them to the for (for [week],[product],[location].
Also I suggest you split calculation and try to check which part is wrong. For example total([a] for [week]) gives you expected result?

Answer (score 1):

You have to be more clearer on what you are trying to achieve. 
Also, the header says framework manager, while you are talking about report. 
My best guess is you need to use the for expression in your aggregate the values:

```
avg((max([a] for [week]))/(sum([b] for [week])))
```

You might need to use other (more sophisticated) summary function 
for more details about the FOR and AT look here:
[Using the AT and FOR Options with Relational Summary Functions](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/cognos/page125.html)